# Who made Captain America's shield and where did the Vibranium come from?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

From the [Wikipedia article about Vibranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Notable_uses) we know:

> It is most known for being used in the construction of Captain America's Shield, the vibranium was of an ultra-resilient vibranium-iron alloy created by Dr. Myron MacLain. The formula has never been reproduced despite numerous attempts.

But in *Captain America: Civil War* Tony Stark mentioned that Captain's shield was made by his father, Howard stark.

So is the shield made by Dr. MacLain (wikipedia source) or Howard Stark (Civil War movie)?

From the wiki, Vibranium is native to Wakanda, and found in Wakanda. How was Captain America's shield made in the earlier films? Or did the films simply not mention the source of Vibranium used to make Captain's shield?

From the Wikipedia article on [Myron MacLain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myron_MacLain):

> Myron MacLain is a fictional character in the Marvel Comics Universe. He is generally credited as the creator of the proto-adamantium alloy that was used to create Captain America's shield and as the creator of adamantium in an effort to re-create the shield.

I guess, there is a movie and comic continuity, and both continuities could be different.

So I think in the movies, the shield was pure Vibranium created by Howard Stark, and in the comics, the shield was made up by an alloy containing Vibranium and was created by the Dr. Myron. Is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the material of Captain America's shield?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49636/what-is-the-material-of-captain-americas-shield)

Comment: Also be aware there is **movie continuity** *and* **comic continuity.** As you provide no link(s), we can't be sure which continuity your are referencing on your wiki reference. Nor do we know *which* wiki you reference. There are many.

Comment: I referenced from wikipedia.com !

Comment: The question seems to ask a different question than the duplicate. The duplicate merely didn't seem to understand what the shield was made of at all, while this question knows what it's made of but asks for a perceived inconsistency about *who* made it and where the material was from.

Comment: Which the all the answers on that one answer.

Comment: Thanks napoleon ! Who and where the material was from,thanks for helping me summarise my question succinctly

Answer (score 6):

Captain America gets his shield during *Captain America: The First Avenger*. They explain that Howard Stark (Tony's father) sent a team into Wakanda, and they discovered a deposit of vibranium.

Stark made the shield (originally as a demonstration of what vibranium can do), but it took all of the vibranium they had. As far as we know, the shield is made entirely of vibranium (in the comics it's usually an alloy but I don't think the movies have ever claimed this.)

Vibranium is an extremely rare and valuable resource -- it's the same material Ulysses Klaw stole in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* -- and we know from the comics that Black Panther is highly protective of his country's vibranium reserves. That's why Cap's shield is so valuable, because there's no vibranium available to make a new one.

Comment: The shield is supposed to be vibranium and adamantium. However, our friend licensing between Marvel (Captain America) and Fox (X-Men, where adamantium is first mentioned) is why the shield is vibranium-only in the movies.